# Partial mocking with MockingKernel for an abstract class?

Tags: unit-testing, ninject, moq, ninject-extensions, ninject-mockingkernel

I have an abstract class with a dependency which I would like to unit test:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
   public BaseClass(IDependency dep) { ... }
   public virtual void TestMethod() { ... }
   ...
}
```

I want to test this class using NInject's [MockingKernel](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.mockingkernel), so I drummed up the following:

```
using (var k = new MoqMockingKernel())
{
   k.Bind<IDependency>().ToMock();
   k.Bind<BaseClass>().ToMock();
   k.GetMock<BaseClass>().CallBase = true;

   var sut = k.Get<BaseClass>();
   sut.TestMethod();

   k.GetMock<BaseClass>().Verify(...);
}
```

but I'm running into a problem.  It's looking for a parameterless constructor to create the partial BaseClass mock rather than passing the mocked IDependency in.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.mockingkernel/blob/master/src/Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq/MoqMockProvider.cs#L102), it appears MockingKernel will *never* pass arguments to a mock at creation time.

Is there any way to create a partial mock with MockingKernel?